# Configure ordering rule in StyleCop Analyzers to enforce user-defined member order

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, roslyn, analyzer, roslyn-code-analysis

Is it possible to configure the StyleCop Analyzers so that "my" order of members within a class (which deviates from what [SA1201](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1201.md) describes) can be checked? Namely I want to have my properties above the constructor whereas SA1201 requires them to be placed below the contructor. I do not want to disable the ordering rule because I do want to stick with having the order being checked.

Comment: Since it's tagged [tag:roslyn] I imagine you're talking about the re-implementation of StyleCop using Roslyn? Looking at the source code for this analyzer I don't think any other configuration is supported since everything is hardcoded: https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/StyleCop.Analyzers/StyleCop.Analyzers/OrderingRules/SA1201ElementsMustAppearInTheCorrectOrder.cs

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I looked at it and I agree it is by far a better approach than writing it from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following just presents the basic idea, but one should really consider looking at what StyleCop-Analyzers do.

Using on the `Analyzer with Code Fix (NuGet + VSIX)` project template I came up with a first draft of an analyzer that is capable of detecting when properties are placed after methods. The implementation of the static `AnalyzeSymbol` method (which is generated on project creation) in the DiagnosticAnalyzer.cs file to achieve this is:

```
private static void AnalyzeSymbol(SymbolAnalysisContext context)
{
  var members = namedTypeSymbol.GetMembers();
  var methods = from m in members
                where (m.Kind == SymbolKind.Method && 
                  !m.IsImplicitlyDeclared && m.CanBeReferencedByName)
                select m;

  var properties = from m in members
                   where m.Kind == SymbolKind.Property
                   select m;

  foreach (var p in properties)
  {
    foreach (var m in methods)
    {
      if (p.Locations.First().SourceSpan.Start > m.Locations.First().SourceSpan.Start)
      {
         // For all such symbols, produce a diagnostic.
         var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, m.Locations[0], m.Name);
         context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
      }
    }
  }
}
```